# xterm doesn't launch in Mojave

Tags: macos, x11

I've installed XQuartz v2.7.11 successfully. However, I'm unable to launch xterm.

```
$ ./xterm 
_
```

Just has my terminal waiting.

My current OS is:

```
System Version: macOS 10.14.6
```

How could I resolve this? Also what further information is required to debug this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This mostly happens when `$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` doesn't contain `/opt/X11/lib`